# AngularJS leaves comments in HTML: is it possible to remove them?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does anyone knows if you can remove the angular comments that are left in html code?

For example: If I use ngRepeat and there are no items to repeat over, AngularJS leaves this :

```
<!-- ngRepeat: post in posts -->
```

Comment: What's the problem with these comments? They're generated at client side, by the angular JavaScript. So they have 0 impact on the download size of the HTML. Why do you care about them?

Comment: should want them there for troubleshooting purposes

Comment: @JBNizet it's a visual pollution when you inspect the DOM.

Comment: It's also a too convenient window into the inner-workings of the application. I'd rather the user not be able to see exactly why something is hidden, or even that there is something there that could be displayed if the scope were modified in some way. In other words, if I hide a delete button from someone, I don't even want them to know that button is available at all. Shouldn't all that info be in memory? Why does Angular need to keep/put all the attributes and comments in the DOM?

Comment: actually they do have an impact `ol:empty { } ` breaks

Comment: It makes inspecting the DOM using DevTools very difficult (in a complex Angular application). I would also like to remove these... but it sounds like doing so would break the app :/

Comment: Man @JBNizet wish I could downvote your ignorant comment

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid instead of insulting, do you have any concrete, factual argument to refute what I said? Do you really think AngularJS includes those comments on the server?

Comment: You can remove comments by 
$("*").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;}).remove();
 But it affect to rebind or modification in scope, Because it uses comments at any changes in scope data.

Comment: I totally agree with @JBNizet about the visual pollution. This is a really annoying when one tries to investigate the "Elements" tab, in order to debug the layout, for example. Those comments made my navigation/debuging a nightmare. In many parts of the layout, one could see more comments than actual markup! I am really surprised to learn that this is a core-angular thing and that we cannot just turn it off... I hope that angular developers will find an other way to achieve what they need, without polluting our markup.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This comment is a result of the *element* transclusion performed by `ngRepeat`. Looks like it's [been happening](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/78656fe0dfc99c341ce02d71e7006e9c05b1fe3f) nearly since the dawn of time (in angular terms) and will be created whenever a directive asks for element transclusion.

While you certainly could wipe it out with direct HTML manipulation, it's not a safe thing to do. Having read through the source, it suggests this comment is needed to continue compiling your HTML once the original `ngRepeat` element is removed. Additionally, in v1.2.0, `ngRepeat` [adds more comments](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9efa46ae640cde17487c341daa9a75c0bd79da02) that are used to determine where repeated elements are placed.

To summarise:

- Angular doesn't let you remove this
- You could do it manually but you would most likely break angular
- <s>To reiterate the comments, it seems a strange request to remove this comment in the first place</s> - depending on your reasoning for doing this there may be better options for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not at all a strange request -- when displaying elements laterally using `inline-block`, comments cause unwanted space where none should be displayed.

Comment: i have strange issue of removing elements after drag & drop and the problem solved after removing comment creation line in ng repeat directive:
clone[clone.length++] = document.createComment(' end ngRepeat: ' + expression + ' ');

Comment: "Not at all a strange request 2" - when you want to use css' `:empty` selector , your element will never be empty because of  this comment inside

Comment: @Cherniv it's not the comment but the whitespace inside that causes the issue with `:empty` but it is still a valid reason

Comment: "Not at all a string request 3" - when you want to generate the final HTML without all ng-bind tag in classes and comments

Comment: "Not at all a strange request 4" - `:first-child`, `:last-child` and `:nth-child` CSS selectors are ruled out to be basically useless inside an `ng-repeat` since they will also match comment nodes..

Comment: I should have crossed that out a lot earlier

Comment: "Not at all a strange request 5" - extra bytes going over the wire

Comment: @jayoaK see the first comment on the question. All client side so shouldn't affect the wire.

Comment: "not at all strange request 5": it is visual pollution of the HTML code

Answer (score 7):

Run this in your dev console to nuke the comments:

```
$("*").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;}).remove();
```

Not a proper fix, but handy snippet while debugging.

Answer (score 4):

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```

But it can broke some plugins which have references on angular comments.

Comment: It does not add `ng-scope` as a class to elements. but those comments stay in the html. https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/docs/guide/production