# Remove helper HTML comments in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to prevent Angular from creating "helper" HTML comments? For example,

```
<div ng-include="myTemplate"></div>
```

Will transform into something like

```
<!-- ngInclude: 'hurr-durr.html' -->
<div ng-include="myTemplate"></div>
```

How do I stop this? I've looked into the Angular source, and I've seen these "helpers" are generated by an unconditional document.createComment inside almost every directive, so I guess there's no way to stop them all at once by using a config setting on a provider or something.
But maybe there is some custom Angular build without "helpers"?
I suppose I could write some Yeoman/Grunt task to remove/comment the .createComment-s from Angular's source whenever I scaffold a new project. Or maybe you guys know of a fiddle that already does that? And also, this raises my last question:
Are those comments somehow crucial to the Angular's normal functioning? And if I remove them, will it cause some kind of instability in my app? Should a just rewrite the CSS and "deal with it"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs leaves comments in HTML is it possible to remove them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments are crucial to how Angular handles certain elements. Removing them is not currently an option. What issues are you having with it?

Comment: Well my team stopped using HTML comments(replacing them with PHP comments) a while ago, since some browsers might match them for :first-child, :last-child, :nth-child and so on. Especially IE.

Comment: I am interested, how does Angular depend on the comments? Do you have an example?

Comment: @Flek Well, I know that you can have comment directives, i.e. <!-- Directive: myDirective --> instead of <div my-directive></div>, but I wasn't sure about the comments generated from actual attribute directives.

Comment: The comments generated are used to find things like ng-if replacement nodes, ng-repeat elements, and so forth. Without them, how would ng-if know where to re-insert itself when the condition is true (coming back from being false)?

Comment: The comment add an undesrired single white space between elements

Answer (score 2):

You are able to remove the contents of these angular comments, as well as some of the classes angular attaches to elements (e.g *ng-scope*) by adding this config to your angular module:

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider)
{
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

According to the [angular.js docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production), it is actually good to do this in production and should result in a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

From Angular Doc:

> ### Disabling Debug Data
>
> By default AngularJS attaches
>   information about binding and scopes to DOM nodes, and adds CSS
>   classes to data-bound elements:
>
> As a result of ngBind, ngBindHtml or {{...}} interpolations, binding
>   data and CSS class ng-binding are attached to the corresponding
>   element.
>
> Where the compiler has created a new scope, the scope and either
>   ng-scope or ng-isolated-scope CSS class are attached to the
>   corresponding element. These scope references can then be accessed via
>   element.scope() and element.isolateScope().
>
> Tools like Protractor and Batarang need this information to run, but
>   you can disable this in production for a significant performance boost
>   with:

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

> If you wish to debug an application with this information then you
>   should open up a debug console in the browser then call this method
>   directly in this console:

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();
```

> The page should reload and the debug information should now be
>   available.
>
> For more see the docs pages on $compileProvider and
>   angular.reloadWithDebugInfo.