# Angular Fills Source with Comments

Tags: angularjs

Is it necessary for Angular to fill my source with comments a la "`<!-- ngRepeat: acct in getAccounts() -->`"?  As in: if I removed them would I be breaking how Angular worked? (I don't know if there's any code that fetches the previous comment from the DOM or something...)

If they're not necessary how can I suppress them?  I can see them being useful for debugging, but not so much in production.

I know it's really two questions, but they're too strongly connected to ask separately.

Comment: Why do you care about them? They're produced dynamically, at client-side. They don't consume any bandwidth or anything.

Comment: 90% because I want to understand, and 10% because when I'm debugging something by inspecting an element they double the time it takes to scroll through.

Comment: +1. Not for practical reasons, but I think this is interesting too.

Comment: but conversely from debugging standpoint....comments can show something that should have been created but wasn't

Comment: Possible duplicates: [duplicate1][1] and [duplicate2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508412/remove-helper-html-comments-in-angular-js

Comment: @besimo, Thanks! I couldn't find those when searching.

Comment: Don't want to delete it...so I'm voting to close my own question...Hopefully it will make finding the answer easier later on.