# Why do Angularjs directives turn into html comments?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do a repeat in a list that I recover from .json file

```
<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
    <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
    <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but when I load the page, it becomes to html comment like

```
<ul class="phones">
  <!-- ngRepeat: phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp -->
</ul>
```

**Webpage**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing angularjs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="script/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
Search: <input ng-model="query">

<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
    <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
    <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**script/Controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);
```

**data/data.json**

```
[
{
 "age": 11,
 "id": "phone1",
 "name": "es un tablet",
 "snippet": "Are you here or not?"
},
{
 "age": 12,
 "id": "phone2",
 "name": "this is a phone",
 "snippet": "Are you sure?"
},
{
 "age": 13,
 "id": "phone3",
 "name": "hello moto",
 "snippet": "Are you seriously ready?"
},
]
```

**Console error**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Dropbox/Web/Angularjs/testFromScratch/app/data/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. 
Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///c://testFromScratch/app/data/data.json'.
    at Error (native)
    at file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:8553:11
    at sendReq (file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:8347:9)
    at $http.serverRequest (file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:8080:16)
    at wrappedCallback (file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:11561:81)
    at wrappedCallback (file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:11561:81)
    at file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:11647:26
    at Scope.$eval (file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:12673:28)
    at Scope.$digest (file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:12485:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///c://testFromScratch/app/script/angular.js:12777:24)
```

Comment: Try to log the data returned in your `$http.get()`, if it's empty then there's something wrong with the `data.json` request.

Comment: $http.get() doesn't get the url, and it gets me an error but I can open the path

Answer (score 1):

You are requiring `phones/phones.json` and the file seems to be labeled `data/data.json`.

The comments are how angular labels its markup (see [Remove helper HTML comments in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508412/remove-helper-html-comments-in-angular-js)).  There are just no phones to list as you've not included the actual data due to using the wrong filename.  When you change the filename the comment will still be there but with a list of phones below.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, that was the original path but I'm using data/data.json and I still have that error.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem with the JSON file you are reading.

Try bypass the file and write directly in the code the data

For example:

```
 $scope.phones = [
                    {
                     "age": 11,
                     "id": "phone1",
                     "name": "es un tablet",
                     "snippet": "Are you here or not?"
                    },
                    {
                     "age": 12,
                     "id": "phone2",
                     "name": "this is a phone",
                     "snippet": "Are you sure?"
                    },
                    {
                     "age": 13,
                     "id": "phone3",
                     "name": "hello moto",
                     "snippet": "Are you seriously ready?"
                    },
                    ];   
$scope.orderProp = 'age';
```

Comment: This way it works good, so it must be $http, but no idea what to do.

Comment: if plain hard coded data works then it means the ajax call is not being performed or data returned from server is faulty.
in order to distinguish between the two you will have to debug using chrome debugger of firebug in fire fox.
make break point at the line where $scope.phones = data and see what is being returned from the server and also watch the web console to see if the ajax called was performed or an error was encountered