# Why my angular code turns to comment?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use angularjs. My html to be comment after render. Why?
Before render code:

`<select data-ng-model="selectedDate">
    <option data-ng-repeat="date in OldRecords" value="{{}}">{{date}}</option>
</select>`

After render:

```
<section>

    <select data-ng-model="selectedDate" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <!-- ngRepeat: date in OldRecords -->
    </select>

</section>
```

Comment: That's an angular *internal*, you shouldn't be bothered by it.

Comment: Angular adds comments, it isn't replaced or anything. You just don't have any dates in oldRecords it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use ng-options in this case ,

There is only a comment shown because $scope.OldRecords either doesn't exist or is empty.

Comment: but this controller has the $scope.OldRecors = ['2014']; Does it must to be the object?

Answer (score 0):

It is a result of the element transclusion performed by ngRepeat.I think it doesn't affect any of your code or logic.
These answers would also help and they also says the same thing

[Remove helper HTML comments in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508412/remove-helper-html-comments-in-angular-js)

[AngularJS leaves comments in HTML: is it possible to remove them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code and its working fine for me. Here is the link for [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5ez79g4/) . Reason you are getting this comments is your list is not able to bind with the options. oldrecords is not able to bind with html. That's the only reason you are getting this comments.

app

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('controller1', function($scope){
    $scope.OldRecords = ["banana", "apple", "peach"];
});
```

html:

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller1">
    {{dummy}}
<select data-ng-model="selectedDate">
    <option data-ng-repeat="date in OldRecords" value="{{}}">{{date}}   </option>
</select>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedDate">
   <option data-ng-repeat="date in OldRecords" value="{{}}">{{date}}</option>
</select>
```

Here `OldRecords` is an Empty Object.So that Angular make that to comment