# Prerender.io and to remove the comments generated by angularjs

Tags: angularjs, prerender

I am using prerender.io to support SEO for my Singlpe Page application built on Angularjs at client side and nodejs at server side. I am hosting prerender.io at my own server. During testing I found that Angualrjs conditional comments are also getting generated by prerender.io. I understand these angularjs comments are maindatory to have when application is being used by browser however when I am rendering page using prerender.io then only purpose is for search engine therefore I don't need these angularjs comments. Following is sample generated page from prerender.io

```
<div data-ng-switch="getModuleType(module,code)">    
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: module1 -->         
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: module2 -->             
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: module3 -->             
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: module4 -->            
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: module5 -->
            <div data-ng-switch-when="module5" class="ng-scope">                               
            </div><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
</div>
```

How I can get rid of these angularjs comments as these are making poor ranking in SEO. Is there a setting in prerender.io?
Please advice.

Comment: Why do you think those comments are affecting your site's ranking? As far as I know, Googlebot (and possibly all other crawlers) [ignores HTML comments](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27060/do-search-engines-see-comments-in-the-source-code-as-a-backlink).

Comment: That's good to know :-) Then i am fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS leaves comments in HTML: is it possible to remove them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them)