# Angular adds a lot of static code to my HTML

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to test my app on a production Rails server and I'm having problems with Angular.

I've commented out `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` in production.rb so I can see the code better.

The problem is that Angular adds a lot of static code to my HTML.

I use router-ui to insert a template in a div called `.search` on my application.html.haml through a State.

In the `.search` div Angular adds this span element.

```
<span class="ng-scope">// Angular Rails Template
// source: app/assets/javascripts/angular-app/templates/_search.html.haml

angular.module("templates").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("angular-app/templates/_search.html", "</span>
```

It also adds a `\n` in the beginning and end of a element.

Like this,

```
<ul id="showresults">\n    <!-- ngRepeat: movie in movieList -->\n  </ul>
```

Angular does work but I have no idea why this extra code is being inserted.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them).

Comment: @muenchdo the comment is not the problem. It's the `\n` and scope tags.

Comment: you can disable ng-scope class with `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`, but ngRepeat comment, you can't unless you modify angular code.

Comment: This isn't about the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying and failing I finally found what the problem was. In my Gemfile.lock if I change `sprockets (3.2.0)` to `sprockets (2.12.4)` the problem occurs. And for some reason when I do `bundle update` the sprockets gem goes from 3.2.0 to 2.14.4. So I have to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically places ng-scope class on elements where scopes are attached, i.e. for controllers, ng-repeat s and etc.

see more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: Okay but why would it add a scope with static HTML when I test the app on a production server?