# Can I prevent angular from inserting newlines in my pre tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

One of my Angular views is a `<pre>` where my model data is rendered as preformatted text to send in an email, like this:

```
<pre>Hello {{name}},
Thank you for your order of
<div ng-repeat="item in orders | filter:{include: true}">Item: {{item.name}}</div>
Sincerely yours
</pre>
```

My problem is that the HTML generated by Angular inserts comments **followed by newlines** which messes up the layout of the email text, like this:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: item in orders | filter:{include: true} -->
```

Is there any way I can keep Angular from doing that?

Comment: Why are you using preformatted text, exactly? Sounds like the best solution is to insert the linebreaks yourself without using `<pre>`

Comment: It seemed like the simplest way to preformat the email text for viewing and copy-paste, but I was probably wrong about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove it, similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them)

But you might solve it with CSS.

```
.parent-of-pre{
    font-size:0;
}

pre{
    font-size:1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding this but did not succeed in making it change the layout (probably my bad). Is the idea that the newlines would then have 0 height? In that case I suppose the newlines would turn up again when the text is copy-pasted?

Comment: Good point. I tried a copy and paste here. When I selected the parsed HTML and pasted the code on Gmail, it removed the comments.